Is it possible to have conditional/dependant input parameters in Angular components?
To make usage of my Angular components easier, I would like to only allow relevant inputs on a component. Is this possible?
I.e. for my component elevensies I would like this to work:
<elevensies [drink]="tea" [milk]="yes" />

or
<elevensies [drink]="water"/>

but not allow the combination:
<elevensies [drink]="water" [milk]="yes" />// Is it possible to give an error when adding "milk" to water?

Is this possible?
Note: using <elevensies [oneInputToRuleThemAll]="{drink:'tea',milk:'yes'}"/> is a fallback solution but my question concerns using separate inputs
ts-file:
@Component({
  selector: "elevensies",
  ...
})
export class ElevensiesComponent {
  readonly drink= input.required<"tea"|"water">();
  readonly milk = input<"yes"|"no">();
}


you can use the power of generics
export class ElevensiesComponent<T extends 'tea' | 'water'> {
  drink = input<T>();
  milk = input<T extends 'water' ? undefined : 'yes' | 'no'>()
}

this way the error of using [milk] input will be compile time error, and not runtime error
[drink]="'water'" [milk]="yes"> // error, as yes is not assignable to undefined


Thank you for the answer, this looks promising! With some aliased/named types this should be easy enough to read as well.

stackblitz demo

just remember that this will work only if drink input is statically analyzable. i.e. if typescript knows that in expression [drink]="tea" typeof tea is "tea"

Building on this, any way to set required on [milk] when drink is set to tea?

no. this is can be done only by one combined object input

You can use effect (reacts to the changes of the signals) and input signals (used to receive inputs like @Input but as a signal) to react to the input params, and throw an error using throw new Error(' ... '), this will force the user to fix the error.
...
export class Elevensies {
  drink: InputSignal<'tea' | 'water'> = input.required();
  milk: InputSignal<'yes' | 'no'> = input<'yes' | 'no'>('no');

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      if (this.drink() !== 'water' && this.milk() !== 'no') {
        throw new Error(
          "Tea can only have milk set as 'yes' as a parameter, so leave milk as no or empty"
        );
      }
    });
  }
}

Full Code:
import { Component, input, InputSignal, effect } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Component({
      selector: 'elevensies',
      standalone: true,
      template: `
        <h1> {{ drink() }}</h1>
      `,
    })
    export class Elevensies {
      drink: InputSignal<'tea' | 'water'> = input.required();
      milk: InputSignal<'yes' | 'no'> = input<'yes' | 'no'>('no');

      constructor() {
        effect(() => {
          if (this.drink() !== 'water' && this.milk() !== 'no') {
            throw new Error(
              "Tea can only have milk set as 'yes' as a parameter, so leave milk as no or empty"
            );
          }
        });
      }
    }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Elevensies],
  template: `
    <elevensies [drink]="'tea'" [milk]="'yes'" />
    <elevensies [drink]="'water'"/>
    <elevensies [drink]="'water'" [milk]="'yes'" /> <!-- should throw error -->
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you! I hope angular will get better validation support for this in the future, but until then I believe this is a good way to solve it!

I would suggest you use a single input with a Discriminate type.
<app-elevensies [drink]="{type: 'Milk'}"></app-elevensies>
<app-elevensies [drink]="{type: 'Tea', milk: false}"></app-elevensies>
<!-- <app-elevensies [drink]="{type: 'Milk', milk: false}"></app-elevensies>. ==> thorws error -->
<!-- <app-elevensies [drink]="{type: 'Tea'}"></app-elevensies> ==> throws error -->

and then the component + type
type Drink =
  | {
      type: 'Tea';
      milk: boolean;
    }
  | {
      type: 'Milk';
    };

@Component({
  selector: 'app-elevensies',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './elevensies.component.html',
  styleUrl: './elevensies.component.css',
})
export class ElevensiesComponent {
  public drink = input.required<Drink>();
}

StackBlitz example

Thank you for the answer. Using one input is a good fallback (and if there is no support from angular this might even be the best way to go) but as I wrote in the question I specifically want to solve the issue using separate inputs.

Oh that's my bad. then one of the other solutions is the better way to go

really not sure what you are trying to say there but, i think you can write some thing like :
<elevensies *ngIf="isValidCombination" [drink]="drink" [milk]="milk">
</elevensies>
<div *ngIf="!isValidCombination" class="error">
Invalid combination: Milk cannot be added to water.
</div>

Or:
@Input() drink: string;
@Input() milk: string;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
 if (this.drink === 'water' && this.milk === 'yes') {
    throw new Error("Milk is not allowed with water.");
 }
}

